# git not available for R / RStudio in macOS Catalina

Tags: r, git, macos, rstudio

I just updated to macOS Catalina (v10.15) and found out that neither `git` commands nor the 'git' pane is available in RStudio after this update.

Now when I open the Terminal pane in RStudio and type:

```
git status
```

I get this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun
```

How to solve this? I downloaded and reinstalled the latest `git` (2.23.0) but that's not working. I use the latest RStudio (1.2.5001) with R 3.6.1.

I changed to the `zsh` shell as Terminal.app suggested when I opened it after the update, with `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From macOS v10.15 (Catalina) on, [`zsh` is the new default shell for new users](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208050), replacing `bash`. I am not sure if this is related to (or causing) the problem, but it might. Depends if the user profile was created after the update, or the user 'activated' `zsh` e.g. by using `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

Behind the scenes, if you run `/usr/bin/git`, the binary loads functions in `libxcselect.dylib` that can locate the path to the real binary, depending on how the system has been configured. One part of this process is to check whether this path contains `usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib`, and the `xcrun` tool, in which case it will invoke `xcrun` to run the binary.

The `xcrun` binary is present in developer directories included with Xcode, so you have to install it. Open Terminal.app and enter:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After this, RStudio will remember `git` again :) Just restart RStudio and everything will be fine.

Comment: zsh is the default *login* shell *for new users*. Unless the OP only created their user profile *after* the update, they will still be using bash.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  Quit RStudio, download Xcode from the app store, open Xcode...it will install developer tools, quit Xcode and open RStudio and Git reappeared.

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution! Installing Xcode completely is overkill, since you only need a small part of it to fix this issue. But I am not downvoting your answer, because it's your first one and I like you to stay motivated to answer (and ask!) more questions :)